# How to change the background music as soon as the game starts?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, avplayer

Hey so I am playing some background music as soon as my app starts. Like a menu song, and it is looping forever throughout the game. I would like to change the music as soon as you hit the start game button. Just so I can have a different menu and game songs. I tried

```
backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
playBackgroundMusic("MUSIC.wav")
```

I did this in my touchesBegan method but of course every time you touch the screen the song is going to start over and over again. Any ideas how I can do this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

While the game starts,if a user touches the initial screen,then it could be identified with a tapGestureRecognizer,in the corresponding class file.
I prefer tap recognising than touchesBegan ,so that, when user touches the screen ,you could play the music via

```
backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
playBackgroundMusic("MUSIC.wav")
```

and stop this by `backgroundMusicPlayer.stop()`when moving on to MENU page.

Then the music wont get played everytime user touches the screen.
I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `AVFoundation`. Follow this basic [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_audio_video.htm) to play audio as soon as the `ViewController` loads, then on clicking the start button stop the audioPlayer.